# Python CSV Import as Complex Nested List, Sort, and Output as Text or Back to CSV

Tags: python, csv, sorting, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I have a data structure, we'll call it an inventory, in CSV that looks similar to:

```
ResID,Building,Floor,Room,Resource
1.1.1.1,Central Park,Ground,Admin Office,Router
1.1.2.1,Central Park,Ground,Machine Closet,Router
1.3.1.1,Central Park,Mezzanine,Dungeon,Whip
2.1.3.1,Chicago,Roof,Pidgeon Nest,Weathervane
1.13.4.1,Central Park,Secret/Hidden Floor,c:\room,Site-to-site VPN for 1.1.1.1
1.2.1.1,Central Park,Balcony,Restroom,TP
```

And I am trying to get it to output in a sorted CSV, and in the format of a text file following the format:

```
1 Central Park
1.1 Ground
1.1.1 Admin Office
1.1.1.1 Router
1.1.2 Machine Closet
1.1.2.1 Router
1.2 Balcony
1.2.1 Restroom
1.2.1.1 TP
1.3 Mezzanine
1.3.1 Dungeon
1.3.1.1 Whip
1.13 Secret/Hidden Floor
1.13.4 c:\room
1.13.4.1 Site-to-site VPN for 1.1.1.1
2 Chicago
2.1 Roof
2.1.3 Pidgeon Nest
2.1.3.1 Weathervane
```

I envision a data structure similar to:

```
Building = {
    1 : 'Central Park',
    2 : 'Chicago'
}
Floor = {
    1 : {
        1 : 'Ground',
        2 : 'Balcony',
        3 : 'Mezzanine',
        13: 'Secret/Hidden Floor'
    },
    2  : {
        1 : 'Roof'
    }
}

Room = {
    1 : {
        1 : {
            1 : 'Admin Office',
            2 : 'Machine Closet'
        }
        2 : {
            1 : 'Restroom'
        }
        3 : {
            1 : 'Dungeon'
        }
... Hopefully by now you get the idea.
```

My complication is that I do not know if this is the best way to represent the data and then iterate over it as:

```
for buildingID in buildings:
    for floorID in floors[buildingID]:
        for roomID in rooms[buildingID][floorID]:
            for resource in resources[buildingID][floorID][roomID]:
                do stuff...
```

Or if there is a MUCH more sane way to represent the data in script, but I need the full document heading numbers AND names intact, and this is the only way I could visualize to do it at my skill level.

I am also at a loss for an effective way to generate this information and build it into the data structure from a CSV in this format.

This may seem trivial to some, but I am not a programmer by trade, and really only dabble on a infrequent basis.

My ultimate goal is to be able to ingest the CSV into a sane data structure, sort it appropriately in ascending numerical order, generate line entries in the text structure shown above that lists each building, floor, room, and resource only once and listed in context with each other, and then ostensibly it would be trivially for me to handle the output to text or back to sorted CSV.

Any recommendations would be GREATLY appreciated.

***EDIT: SOLUTION***

Leveraging my accepted answer below I was able to generate the following code. Thank you to the guy that deleted his answer and comments that simplified my sorting process too!

```
import csv

def getPaddedKey(line):
    keyparts = line[0].split(".")
    keyparts = map(lambda x: x.rjust(5, '0'), keyparts)
    return '.'.join(keyparts)

def outSortedCSV(reader):
    with open(fOutName, 'w') as fOut:
        writer = csv.writer(fOut, delimiter=',')
        head = next(reader)
        writer.writerow(head)
        writer.writerows(sorted(reader, key=getPaddedKey))

s = set()
fInName = 'fIn.csv'
fOutName = 'fOut.csv'

with open(fInName, 'r') as fIn:
    reader = csv.reader(fIn, delimiter=',')
    outSortedCSV(reader)
    fIn.seek(0)
    next(fIn)
    for row in reader:
        ids = row[0].split('.')      # split the id
        for i in range(1, 5):
            s.add(('.'.join(ids[:i]), row[i])) # add a tuple with initial part of id and name

for e in sorted(list(s), key=getPaddedKey):
    print e[0] + '  ' + e[1]
```

Comment: Not really. Thats about the long and short. Sort the data, and output to text in the right section of the text file building each heading from the content in csv.

Comment: And to build a text document sorted and labeled as per my example above where numbers of resources may reach into triple-digits at the 4th level of the hierarchy.

Comment: My biggest problem is visualizing how to store and sort the data effectively. I think I can figure how to manage the iteration over the resultant data set, and output

Comment: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(list(df['ResID'].str.split('.')), columns=['Building_id', 'Floor_id', 'Room_id', 'Resource_id']))` can help to connect a 'Building' and 'Building_id'

Comment: @MaartenFabré Thanks. I think I understand this part. I can extract and correlate the IDs to their textual description, but I do not understand how to organize this data in mass, maintain an interrelationship, and properly sort the in memory data, and prepare for output in the format identified (including de-duplication of redundant buildings, floors, and rooms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no reason to build your proposed structure, you could simply add for each line the building, floor, room and resource along with its id to a set (to automatically eliminate duplicates). Then you convert the set to a list, sort it and you are done.

Possible Python code, assuming `rd` is a `csv.reader` on the inventory (*):

```
next(rd)                         # skip the headers line
s = set()
for row in rd:
    ids = row[0].split('.')      # split the id
    for i in range(1, 5):
        s.add(('.'.join(ids[:i]), row[i])) # add a tuple with initial part of id and name
l = list(s)                      # convert to a list
l.sort()                         # sort it
```

You have now a list of 2-tuples `[('1', 'Central Park'), ('1.1', 'Ground'), ('1.1.1', 'Admin Office'), ...]`, you can use it to build a new csv or just print it as text:

```
for i in l:
    print(" ".join(i))
```

---

(*) In Python 3, you would use:

```
with open(inventory_path, newline = '') as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    ...
```

while in Python 2, it would be:

```
with open(inventory_path, "rb") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    ...
```

Comment: OK. This may sound stupid, but what is the proper initialization of s in the above example?

Comment: Never mind. By more careful reading I was able to determine that it should be:

    s=set()

Comment: @daijizai Looks like I had missed a line... Edited

Answer (score 0):

## extract the id's

```
ids = ['Building_id', 'Floor_id', 'Room_id', 'Resource_id']
labels = ['ResID', 'Building', 'Floor', 'Room', 'Resource']

df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(list(df['ResID'].str.split('.')), columns=ids))
```

> ```
>  df2
> ```

```
    ResID   Building    Floor   Room    Resource    Building_id     Floor_id    Room_id     Resource_id
0   1.1.1.1     Central Park    Ground  Admin Office    Router  1   1   1   1
1   1.1.2.1     Central Park    Ground  Machine Closet  Router  1   1   2   1
2   1.3.1.1     Central Park    Mezzanine   Dungeon     Whip    1   3   1   1
3   2.1.3.1     Chicago     Roof    Pidgeon Nest    Weathervane     2   1   3   1
4   1.13.4.1    Central Park    Secret/Hidden Floor     c:\room     Site-to-site VPN for 1.1.1.1    1   13  4   1
5   1.2.1.1     Central Park    Balcony     Restroom    TP  1   2   1   1
```

## iterate over this

little helper method

```
def pop_list(list_):
    while list_:
        yield list_[-1], list_.copy()
        list_.pop()


for (id_, remaining_ids), (label, remaining_labels) in zip(pop_list(ids), pop_list(labels)):

    print(label, ': ', df2.groupby(remaining_ids)[label].first())
```

returns

```
Resource :  Building_id  Floor_id  Room_id  Resource_id
1            1         1        1                                    Router
                       2        1                                    Router
             13        4        1              Site-to-site VPN for 1.1.1.1
             2         1        1                                     TP   
             3         1        1                                      Whip
2            1         3        1                               Weathervane
Name: Resource, dtype: object

Room :  Building_id  Floor_id  Room_id
1            1         1            Admin Office
                       2          Machine Closet
             13        4                 c:\room
             2         1                Restroom
             3         1                 Dungeon
2            1         3            Pidgeon Nest
Name: Room, dtype: object

Floor :  Building_id  Floor_id
1            1                        Ground
             13          Secret/Hidden Floor
             2                       Balcony
             3                     Mezzanine
2            1                          Roof
Name: Floor, dtype: object

Building :  Building_id
1    Central Park
2         Chicago
Name: Building, dtype: object
```

### Explanation

```
for (id_, remaining_ids), (label, remaining_labels) in zip(pop_list(ids), pop_list(labels)):
    print((id_, remaining_ids), (label, remaining_labels))
```

returns

```
('Resource_id', ['Building_id', 'Floor_id', 'Room_id', 'Resource_id']) ('Resource', ['ResID', 'Building', 'Floor', 'Room', 'Resource'])
('Room_id', ['Building_id', 'Floor_id', 'Room_id']) ('Room', ['ResID', 'Building', 'Floor', 'Room'])
('Floor_id', ['Building_id', 'Floor_id']) ('Floor', ['ResID', 'Building', 'Floor'])
('Building_id', ['Building_id']) ('Building', ['ResID', 'Building'])
```

So this just iterates over the different levels in your building structure

```
res = df2.groupby(remaining_ids)[label].first()
```

builds per level in your structure a DataFrame representing the items at this level with as (Multi)index the nested ID's to this level. This is the info you want  for your eventual datatructure, it just needs to be transformed to a nested `dict`

```
Building_id  Floor_id
1            1                        Ground
             13          Secret/Hidden Floor
             2                       Balcony
             3                     Mezzanine
2            1                          Roof
```

### to text (no nesting)

```
res.index = res.index.to_series().apply('.'.join)
print(res)
```

> ```
> 1.1                  Ground
> 1.13    Secret/Hidden Floor
> 1.2                 Balcony
> 1.3               Mezzanine
> 2.1                    Roof
> Name: Floor, dtype: object
> ```

Comment: I will need to spend some time playing with this to see if I can even understand it enough to build the textual representation in the format that I need out of this; however, it does seem to build a sane data structure per your example output.

Comment: I am having trouble walking through what pd and df should be in order to get to df2 in this example. assuming the csv open as csvIn and advanced past the header row, can you point me towards the appropriate initialization of pd and df to get my data into df2?